# How to get a users profile pics to be viewed by other users using PHP?

Tags: php, html

All I am looking for is when the below code is run and the Albums or the Music links are clicked it posts to the same page, correct? hence the url changes and add the href on the end of it depending on the link clicked.  Well how can I call the following when the link is clicked:

```
<?php echo 'Albums';?>
```

Original code:

```
if(isset($_GET['username']) === true && empty($_GET['username']) === false){
$username       = $_GET['username'];

if(user_exists($username) === true){
$user_id        = user_id_from_username($username);
$profile_data   = user_data($user_id, 'first_name','last_name','email');
?>

    <h1><?php echo $profile_data['first_name']; ?>'s Yor Page</h1>




<div id="navWrapper">


    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#"><img src="uploads/profile/blank_profile.gif" width="150" height="150" id="blank_profile"></a>
        </li>

        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="?albums">Albums</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="?music">Music</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </ul>

</div>
<?php
}else{
    echo 'Sorry, that user doesn\'t exist';
}
}else{
header('Location: index.php');
exit();
}

include 'includes/overall/overall_footer.php';
?>
```

Now I have the link setup when clicked it returns yorpage.com/lr/username?albums,  how can I call a php function or statement when I click on this link and go to url yorpage.com/lr/username?albums?

So a simple echo would be fine for demonstration purposes just to get a return on the click is what I am looking for.  If you need more info, I don't think you do I'm not asking to code this for me I can return the images or albums etc. I just want to find out how to handle that link being clicked and returning a simple echo when Albums or Music links are clicked.  Thank You.

Comment: i will kill myself next time i see some one else create a facebook clone.

Comment: You should really shorten your explanations and ask clearly what the problem is. I got completely lost in your source code / text.

Comment: @Dagon Right, I'm gonna do it now :-P **EDIT** After a little research, I have discovered that the wheel has already been invented. Who knew?

Comment: yes, but does it come in a full range of colours?

Comment: Well go ahead Dagon go for it buddy, by the way this is a project! If you can not provide help and guidance please do not comment, people on here are here to learn!!!!

Comment: Sorry I meant a class project I am in school right now trying to figure this out.

Comment: @AaronWarnke OK I'll freely admit that we have been been quick to ridicule this, and slightly unreasonably so (I remind all of you regulars of [this](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/07/kicking-off-the-summer-of-love/)) *but*... you question has a huuuuge block of quite unreadable text, and is a little non-specific about exactly where you are having the problem *from a coding standpoint*. Can you try and cut it down a bit so that a) it's more readable and b) it comes to the point a little quicker?

Comment: Ok I have updated my question, hopefully you understand what Im asking.

Comment: yes we are terrible, but having seen so many clones of facebook questions here in the past it gets a little painful for the regulars. How many of your school buddies are doing the same thing? perhaps your teachers would like to see something other than facebook clones to!. And lastly please use the homework tag for school questions.

Comment: No one is I am doing an independent project where we can choose to create a website that uses mysql, html, php, css, javascript etc.  I am going a little above and beyond but that is why I keep a 3.70 GPA.  And I will use the homework tag never knew there was one as there are a lot of tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a little lost but as I understood, your question is: How can I pass arguments in the url so that when I go to the URL http://www.example.com/username/albums it goes to albums right?

here's an example of something similar:

```
    if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
        $pageArgs = explode('/', $_GET['page']);
        if(isset($pageArgs[0])) {
            $username = $pageArgs[0];   
        } else {
            header('Location: index.php');
            exit();     
        }
        $action = (isset($pageArgs[1])) ? $pageArgs[1] : false;
        switch($action)
        {
            case 'albums':
                print 'These are my albums <br/>';
                break;
            case 'music':
                print 'This is my music! <br/>';
                break;

            default:
                print '
                    <nav>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="'.$username.'/albums">Albums</a></li>
                            <li><a href="'.$username.'/music">Music</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>';
                break;
        }
    }
```

Adapt this to your needs...

NOTE: Please note that I changed the argument to page instead of username so you have to update your rewrite mod rules. I also used / to separate page "arguments". You can use "?" (i think, not sure) if you prefer...

---

This following a simple MVC

### index.php

```
// Find which page is requested
$pageIDs = pageSelector();
// namespaced pages. You can change to real namespaces with:
// $mPage = '\\Page\\' . $pageIDs[0];
$mPage = 'Page_' . $pageIDs[0];
array_shift($pageIDs);

// Path to Template file (the static elements common to all pages like
// header, footer, logo, navigation, etc...
$templatePath = 'templates/my_template.html';

if(!empty($pageIDs))
    $pageArgs = $pageIDs;
else
    $pageArgs = false;

//create Page Object, the dynamic content divided by sections
//for instance, content, columnA, columnB   
$page = new $mPage($pageArgs);

$template = new Template($templatePath, $page);

//Here's an example of a section
$template->addSection('subNavigation');

print $template;

// PageSelector Function
function pageSelector()
{
    if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
        $pIDs = explode('/', $_GET['page']);    
    } else {
        $pIDs = array('home');
    }
    $pagePath = 'pages/' . $pIDs[0] . '.php';
    if (file_exists($pagePath)) {
        require_once($pagePath);
        return $pIDs;
    } else {
        $pagePath = 'pages/home.php';
        require_once($pagePath);
        return array('home');
    }
}



//Template Object
class Template
{
    private $path, $page;
    private $sections = array('content');

    public function __construct($tPath, $page)
    {
        $this->path = $tPath;
        $this->page = $page;
    }

    public function addSection($newSectionName)
    {
        $this->sections[] = $newSectionName;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        $html = file_get_contents($this->path);
        foreach($this->sections as $section) {
            $html = str_replace('[%%'.$section.'%%]', $this->page->show($section), $html);
        }
        return $html;
    }
}
```

---

### file pages/home.php

```
class Page_home
{
    public function __construct($args) {}

    public function show($section)
    {
        switch($section)
        {
            case 'content':
                return 'this is my main page';
            break;

            default:
                return '';
            break;
        }
    }   
}
```

---

### file pages/user.php

```
class Page_user
{
    private $subPage;
    public function __construct($args)
    {
        if(isset($args[0])) 
            $this->username = $args[0];
        else {
            $this->username = false;
            return;
        }
        if(isset($args[1]))
            $this->subPage = $args[1];
        else {
            $this->subPage = false;
            return;
        }

    }

    public function show($section)
    {
        if($this->username)
        {
            switch($section)
            {
                case 'content':
                    $otp  = 'My username is ' . $this->username . '<br/>';
                    $otp .= $this->showSubPage();
                    return $otp;
                break;

                case 'subNavigation':
                    return $this->nav();
                break;

                default:
                    return '';
                break;
            }   
        } else {
            return 'username not found!';
        }
    }

    protected function nav()
    {
        return
        '<nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="user/'.$this->username.'/albums">Albums</a></li>
                <li><a href="user/'.$this->username.'/music">Music</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>';    
    }

    protected function showSubPage()
    {
        switch($this->subPage)
        {
            case 'albums':
                return 'These are my albums <br/>';
                break;
            case 'music':
                return 'This is my music! <br/>';
                break; 
        }
    }
}
```

### templates/my_template.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mainNav">myLink | Go | Here</div>
    <nav id="subNav">[%%subNavigation%%]</nav>
    <div id="content">[%%content%%]</div>
    <footer>my (c) copyright notice</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes that did it and you even cleaned up the url for me!  Thank You

Comment: no prob mate!!!! Btw, if it's for school and you really want to impress, instead of using spaghetti PHP (mixing presentation[HTML] with code[PHP]), try separating your code from the template. Check my edited answer for an example.

Answer (score 1):

I might be confused (as that was a lot of text), but I think what you're looking for is a tutorial on htaccess... Use a rewrite rule to silently convert a url:

```
http://domain/[username]/album
```

to

```
http://domain.com?script.php?user=[username]&action=album
```

... or something like that. The user will see the first url, but the script will have access to `user` and `action` in the `$_GET` array... then you can just check

```
if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action']=='album'){ //do something...
```

There are tons of tutorials out there for this, but here's the [first one](http://www.9lessons.info/2009/11/pretty-urls-with-htaccess-file.html) I found.

Comment: No not exactly what I was looking for I guess I don't know how to word my question right but that was very helpful, thank you.